Efficiently Retrieving Start and End Times for Large Sets of TXIDs in Splunk
I am trying to load txids from a lookup file and, for each txid, get the earliest and latest times to print the information in a table.
Here are the steps I have tried so far:
First, I loaded txids from a lookup file using the following query:
| inputlookup cached_txids.csv
| search to_release="<release_name>"
| makemv delim=" " txids
| mvexpand txids
| table txids

Next, I picked one of the txids from the list and verified that the information is showing up:
    txid="<txid_value>"
    | stats earliest(_time) as upgrade_start_time, latest(_time) as upgrade_end_time by txid
    | eval upgrade_start_time_human=strftime(upgrade_start_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    | eval upgrade_end_time_human=strftime(upgrade_end_time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    | table txid, upgrade_start_time_human, upgrade_end_time_human

Then, I combined the first two steps using JOIN with the goal of printing the txids along with their start and end times:
| inputlookup cached_txids.csv
| search to_release="<release_name>"
| makemv delim=" " txids
| mvexpand txids
| join type=inner txids [
    search *
    | rex field=_raw "txid=(?<txids>[^\s]+)"
    | stats earliest(_time) as start_time latest(_time) as end_time by txids
]
| table txids, start_time, end_time

However, this ^ just prints the txids but not their start and end times.
I'm seeking help to find a way to achieve my goal of using JOIN command and to make this query work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

First, avoid the join command whenever possible because it does not perform well.
This problem calls for a subsearch.  In Splunk, subsearches run first and return their results to become part of the main search.  In this case, the inputlookup would be the subsearch so the txids values could be used to qualify what should be located in the index.
index=foo ```Always specify an index``` [ | inputlookup cached_txids.csv where to_release="<release_name>"
  | makemv delim=" " txids
  | mvexpand txids
  | fields txids
  | rename txids as txid ```Change the field name to match what is in the index ```
  | format ]
| stats earliest(_time) as start_time latest(_time) as end_time by txids
| table txids, start_time, end_time

